# Set default paper size of printer via mac terminal command

Tags: macos, bash, printing, terminal

I'm using a mac and want to set the default page size of a printer just before I send a job to it via a script.

Please could somebody tell me what the bash mac terminal script would look like

Thanks
David

Comment: Any code? How are you sending the job to your printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears you can edit use default to overwrite the default paper by name like this...

defaults write com.apple.print.PrintingPrefs DefaultPaperID -string 91x61